# Showing time on ProgressBar in Android

Tags: java, android

Now,i have created progress bar and i want to allot time for progress bar(Ex. 2min)
and user must able to see  time while running progress bar.
how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update your ProgressBar using [***CountDownTimer***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    bar.setProgress(total);
    int twoMin = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutes in milli seconds

    /** CountDownTimer starts with 2 minutes and every onTick is 1 second */
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(twoMin, 1000) { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            total = (int) ((dTotal / 120) * 100);
            bar.setProgress(total);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
             // DO something when 2 minutes is up
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: @GauravAgarwal: no, based on its 1-screen source it uses a default handler so each `tick` and `finish` is called on the Main Looper (i.e. UI). If you want to periodically execute something in background you can start your `AsyncTask` on `onTick`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use progress dialog rather using progress bar.Again for setting it is also possible using thread in progress dialog.

Please check this [link](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_displaying_a_simple_progressdialog-t250.html).Also link from official android blog. [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) Please see **Creating  Progress Dialog** & in that second example using thread.

Comment: ok...how to achieve it with thread in progress dialog.?can you please give some links or sample for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Onkar... AsyncTask can both host the time intensive task and report progress, IF the time intensive task can be broken up into sub-tasks. AsyncTask uses generics to accomplish its magic. The progress type would be the middle type of the three "required formal type parameters" being `<Params,Progress,Result>`.

JAL