# How to implement CountDownTimer Class in Xamarin C# Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin.Android framework. I am working on count down timer but unable to implement like  the [java `CountDownTimer`  class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). Could anybody please help me out to convert following java [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113960/showing-time-on-progressbar-in-android) to C# Xamarin android code.

```
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    bar.setProgress(total);
    int twoMin = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutes in milli seconds

    /** CountDownTimer starts with 2 minutes and every onTick is 1 second */
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(twoMin, 1000) { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            total = (int) ((dTotal / 120) * 100);
            bar.setProgress(total);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
             // DO something when 2 minutes is up
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: can u tell me  how to run this code on ui thread xamarin android

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like the class you need is [CountDownTimer](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.OS.CountDownTimer), and so it should just be a simple matter of porting that code from Java to C#

Comment: I happened to have this problem also. The way we use `CountDownTimer` on Java is way different from what the C# syntax allow us to do. I did an implementation of `CountDownTimer` as a child class on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/arlm/8260067). Please reopen the question so that I can answer what he needs. P.S.: I edited the question in order to have it better explained and to have the original Java source code that he needs to be converted.

Comment: No idea why this was closed as unclear. It seems pretty obvious.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why not use [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for this?

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
private int _countSeconds;

void Main()
{
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    //Trigger event every second
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    //count down 5 seconds
    _countSeconds = 5;

    _timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _countSeconds--;

    //Update visual representation here
    //Remember to do it on UI thread

    if (_countSeconds == 0)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

An alternative way would be to start an async `Task`, which has a simple loop inside and cancel it using a `CancellationToken`.

```
private async Task TimerAsync(int interval, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // do your stuff here...

        await Task.Delay(interval, token);
    }
}
```

Then start it with

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(5000); // 5 seconds

TimerAsync(1000, cts.Token);
```

Just remember to catch the `TaskCancelledException`.

Comment: thanks for reply can u tell me how to run this code on ui thread xamarin android?

Comment: `RunOnUiThread(() => { /* update UI here */ });`